# Backward stepwise selection to choose an optimal subset of the predictors with the AUC as a criterion

Tags: python, logistic-regression, feature-selection

I am looking to perform a backward feature selection process on a logistic regression with the AUC as a criterion. For building the logistic regression I used the scikit library, but unfortunately this library does not seem to have any methods for backward feature selection. My dependent variable is a binary banking crisis variable and I have 13 predictors. Does anybody have any suggestions on how to handle this?

The code below states the method to compute the AUC. The problem is that I do not know how to decide which feature I can prune because it is less important than the other.

```py
def cv_loop(X, y, model, N):
    mean_auc = 0.
    for i in range(N):
        X_train, X_cv, y_train, y_cv = train_test_split(
                                       X, y, test_size=.20, 
                                       random_state = i*SEED)
        model.fit(X_train, y_train)
        preds = model.predict_proba(X_cv)[:,1]
        fpr, tpr, _ = metrics.roc_curve(y_cv, preds)
        auc = metrics.auc(fpr, tpr)
        print("AUC (fold %d/%d): %f" % (i + 1, N, auc))
        mean_auc += auc
    return mean_auc/N
```

If you need more background information let me know!

Many thanks in advance,

Joris

Answer (score 0):

scikit-learn has [Recursive Feature Elimination (RFE)](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.RFE.html) in its `feature_selection` module, which almost does what you described.

> Given an external estimator that assigns weights to features (e.g.,
> the coefficients of a linear model), the goal of recursive feature
> elimination (RFE) is to select features by recursively considering
> smaller and smaller sets of features. First, the estimator is trained
> on the initial set of features and the importance of each feature is
> obtained either through a coef_ attribute or through a
> feature_importances_ attribute. Then, the least important features are
> pruned from current set of features. That procedure is recursively
> repeated on the pruned set until the desired number of features to
> select is eventually reached.

This doesn't explicitly work on AUC however. It does the prunining by looking at coefficients of the logistic regression.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I found this module as well, but unfortunately that does not solve my problem, as I need to use AUC as the maximizing criterion.